# Where are the additional command line options in Android Studio version 1.5.1 for the emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, command-line, android-emulator, http-proxy

After the latest update to AS, the emulator's additional command line options are missing. I use this primarily for -http-proxy and -scale commands. Any help in locating these options, or it's replacement, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a known bug in version 1.5:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195031

The *Emulator* tab has disappeared from the *Run Configurations*. You can try to downgrade to 1.4.1:

http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/1-4-1

Comment: Sad update: 2.1.2 still exhibits this (lack of) behavior.

Comment: Sad update: 2.2.2 still has no fix, after nearly a year.

Comment: The bug posted was marked as "duplicate of WON'T FIX" issue from 2015... https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37071130#comment6 and AVD Manager doesn't seem to have any option to change the existing device's settings, nor an input to define new device's command line options

Comment: I opened a bug report to have it added to AVD Manager... https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38338883

Comment: @jakub.g Good idea, and please everyone wanting this consider starring the issue.

Comment: It's finally available on the canary channel (26.1. emulator)