# Android AVDs not working with hardware acceleration

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, android-virtual-device

```
4.9.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.18-1 (2017-03-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
Android Studio 2.3.3
```

When I try to run an AVD with hardware acceleration I get this error:

```
emulator -avd n5 -verbose
...
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
...
```

So then I tried to use my system libraries ( running with **-use-system-libs**) and it started but the display small but it does accept input:

[image]

EDIT 1: The the input is borked still but I think I know why the screen is so small, I have a high density display. Perhaps there is a way to compensate for this?

EDIT 2: It does accept input (there was just some lag). So the problem is just the small screen. I've tried a variety of AVD images but all have the same issue.

Comment: [Does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35911302/cannot-launch-emulator-on-linux-ubuntu-15-10)?

Comment: No my problem isn't finding the library, Ive already identified that issue ( -use-system-libs ). If I use my system library it runs but runs messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with screen scaling.

I use KDE plasma with a screen scalling setting of 1.5 which caused this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a 15" 4k display, so disabling scaling globally was not an option for me. Instead I was looking to disable scaling for the avd only.

Unfortunately I was unable to add `QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=1` as a parameter before the emulator command in [android studio settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644264/where-are-the-additional-command-line-options-in-android-studio-version-1-5-1-fo).

What I ended up doing was renaming `{$ANDROID_SDK}/emulator/emulator` binary and placing a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=1 {FULL_path_to_sdk_here}/emulator/emulator.trick "$@"
```

This worked great for me, and I have not noticed any drawback.
To my surprise the emulator didn't show up really tiny, instead it now fills the whole size of the original window!

Comment: I was after this for a while...you made my day..thanks a lot