# Provide Additional command line options to AVD in Android Studio 2.3.3?

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator, kvm

**Trying to setup kvm on ubuntu here.**

The official docs only points to [ubuntu docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html#vm-linux) to install kvm 
The steps provided [here](https://github.com/uw-it-aca/spacescout-android/wiki/1.-Setting-Up-Android-Studio-on-Ubuntu#install-intels-kvm-for-better-avd-performance%20and%20here) and [here](http://charlieraffellini.com/Enable-KVM-in-Debian/)
Says to  In Android Studio

1. Go to Run > Edit Configurations.
2. To set as global default for all projects, select "Android
   Application" under "Defaults".
3. Go to the emulator tab, check "Additional command line options"
4. Add -qemu -m 2047 -enable-kvm

The **tab is not present** in 2.3.3 and has been a [know issue since 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34744479/4179914)

But the issue has been [reported and closed](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37071130) as intended behavior with no valid answer to on where to run 
`-qemu -m 2047 -enable-kvm`

**Update 1**
KVM is supported

```
nishon@nishon-Inspiron-5420 ~ $ kvm-ok
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used

nishon@nishon-Inspiron-5420 ~ $ egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Passing the additional while launching avd from bash shell seems to be
>   working. I am entirely not sure though.

```
 nishon@nishon-Inspiron-5420 ~ $ emulator -avd [Enter AVD name] -qemu -m 2047 -enable-kvm
```

Before tying this command you need to setup path to ADB in your .bashrc(Ubuntu) or path(Windows)

Reference https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html

Answer (score 0):

I too need that additional command line option for emulator

but anyhow i found a alternative way for it...
go to the sdk/tools

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools
```

run this command to start avd using system libraries..

```
./emulator -avd YOUR_AVD_NAME -use-system-libs
```

the apps worked fine for me when the emulator is running in the background.